# Is there anyway to update an exising array defined inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

There is a static array which should be dynamically updated based upon click event.

I am able to get the dynamic value in an array format using Ajax but finding difficulties in setting it to the existing variable.

Ajax returns the below array

```
echo json_encode($arry);
// ["2","1","1","0","1","0"]
```

```
$.post( "ajaxcall.php", { ids: id })
   .done(function( returnedArray){
      //returnedArray looks like ["2","1","1","0","1","0"]
      datasets: [{
                  //data: [10,12,33,50,12,34]
                  data: returnedArray
                 }]
     },
```

But after the click event, returnedArray does not get interpreted to place the value.

Bacialy the result should look like below:

```
data: ["2","1","1","0","1","0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the assignment operator instead of `:`

```
datasets = [{
     //data: [10,12,33,50,12,34]
     data: returnedArray
}]
```

Comment: Actually I have put the trimmed code in my query. There are other variables and value under ```datasets``` which are comma separated. When I use ```=``` to assign the value then it throws an error and says that ```:``` is missing.

Comment: For an example the in actual code looks like below:
``` datasets = [{
     //data: [10,12,33,50,12,34]
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false, 
    data: returnedArray
    }]
```

Comment: @Shashi Roy Can't say anything with seeing the all code. But `datasets: [{
                  //data: [10,12,33,50,12,34]
                  data: returnedArray
                 }]
     }` inside a function will never change the value of `datasets`